# How to set font for diffrent devices

Tags: android

i am creating simple app to show notifications. i want large font on large devices and small fonts on small devices. Please Help.

Following is screen shot of tablet of dpi - 213
[image]

Following Screen shot of Moto G3 phone have dpi - 320

[image]

Comment: which unit are you using for Text ?

Comment: Are you aware that you must use **sp** for text sizes?

Comment: that's what sizes are for ?

Comment: i am using sp for text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create different values folder as per required ***screen sizes and resolution*** and put '**dimens.xml**' file in each folder.

For example:

For HDPI device- you need to create folder with this name

```
"values-sw320dp-hdpi" under this folder put "dimens.xml"
```

For Large HDPI device- you need to create folder with this name

```
"values-large-hdpi-1024x600" under this folder put "dimens.xml"
```

For MDPI device- you need to create folder with this name

```
"values-sw320dp-mdpi" under this folder put "dimens.xml"
```

Similarlily you can create different values folders for other devices too under "**res**" folder.

**Now, what next to do and How it works:**

Say, you have TextView defined in your xml and you need different font sizes on different devices:

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"    // This is the important line
 android:text="Hello"/>
```

Now, here '**dimens.xml**' file comes into picture. You need to specify different size value of "**textSize**" under different dimens.xml w.r.t screen sizes and resolution

For Example:

For HDPI device:    res>values-sw320dp-hdpi>**dimens.xml**

```
 <dimen name="textSize">19sp</dimen>  // Setting size of Text for HDPI devices
```

For MDPI device:    res>values-sw320dp-mdpi>**dimens.xml**

```
 <dimen name="textSize">15sp</dimen>  // Setting size of Text for MDPI devices
```

Similarly, you can define sizes for other screen too.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to display app in same size on all screen sizes with writing minimum code. i don't want to write sizes for all screens

Answer (score 0):

You should use styles, then you can have separate folders "values" (default) "values-hdpi" (high density) "values-mdpi" (medium density) and so on and put your style file with correct textSize values in each folder as needed.

Then, when you are in medium density device it will pick the file in "values-mdpi" folder if exists or in "values" if not, and the same for high density etc...

This same principle applies to al "res" subfolders